# How to print values of an object in Play

Tags: java, playframework

In Groovy, there is a function called `.dump()` that "Generates a detailed dump string of an object showing its class, hashCode and fields".

Is there any equivalent method in Play framework (1.2.5), or does Java provide any such method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent in core Java. Most people make do with the capabilites of the debugger.

You could implement something similar using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/) and I wouldn't be surprised if there are 3rd party libraries that has it.

You could also create a Dumper class based on [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) and Json:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver;
...
XStream dumper = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
System.out.println(dumper.toXML(data));
```